# Exploding all possible combinations of two columns in a table

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have the following tables:

`t1`:

```
ID      POC     SID      VALUE
===============================
50      poc1     1         2

51      poc1     1         3
51      poc1     2         1

53      poc4     1         1
53      poc5     2         2
```

`t2`:

```
ID      POC     
===============
50      poc1    

51      poc1    
51      poc2    

53      poc4    
53      poc5
```

### See this [DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/k5yoikWZXhj5qg9PdwuggX/0).

And I want the result of joining these two tables in one table below where I have a all possible combinations of `(POC, SID)` within every partition of `ID`:

```
ID      POC     SID      VALUE
===============================
50      poc1    1          2

51      poc1    1          3
51      poc2    1        (null)
51      poc1    2          1
51      poc2    2        (null)

53      poc4    1          1
53      poc5    1        (null)  
53      poc4    2        (null)  
53      poc5    2          2
```

So `poc4` and `poc5` only appear under an `ID` of `53` and no other.

What would be the SQL query to get the above result?

Comment: What flavor of sql?

Comment: Do you have two other separate tables containing all possible `ID` and `POC` values

Comment: @DanielA.White Bigquery

Comment: @Charlieface yes,  can get all possible combinations of ID and POC.

Comment: OK do you have a separate table of all possible SID values also?

Comment: I do not have that.

Comment: So why does `50      poc1` get only SID `1` and not `2` but `51      poc2` gets both, with null? I really don't think the results make much sense, you need to go through step by step and work out what your rules are to create the result. Putting it another way, if `SID` in the results could end up with nulls, and you didn't want multiple missing `SID` results then it would make sense https://dbfiddle.uk/SkFiNYYR

Comment: Because from the `t1` table, the only possible value for `SID` for `ID`=`50` is `1`, whereas for `ID`=`51` are `1` *and* `2`.

Comment: Yeah, that's the thing - the results only contain nulls in `SID` for those `ID` that are in `t2` but not `t1`.
For now, we can make this simpler by ignoring those rows for now, see: https://dbfiddle.uk/FBny5qXN

Comment: So the logic is kind of: if there is a row then *oonly* use that, otherwise join all possible SID? That's a really strange type of join.

Comment: Actually, it's like - for every `ID`, get all possible `POC` from `t2` and all possible `SID` from `t1` and create all possible combinations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to start with `t2` and  left join `t1`.

```sql
SELECT
  t2.ID,
  t2.POC,
  t1.SID,
  t1.Value
FROM t2
LEFT JOIN t1
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID
 AND t1.POC = t2.POC
ORDER BY
  ID,
  POC,
  SID;
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/FBny5qXN)

Comment: Thanks, but won't this give me *all* possible combinations of `ID` and `POC`, eg: `(50, poc4)`, which I don't want in my result?

Comment: I'm confused, isn't that what you wanted? Please be clearer about what exactly you want. Maybe you need a table of all possible *combinations* of `ID` and `POC`, then cross-join with `SID`?

Comment: Apologies. I have added a couple of edits to the question. I want combinations within each partition of ‘ID’, so ‘poc4’ and ‘poc5’ only appear under an ‘ID’ of ‘53’ and no other.

Comment: OK so you need a table of all those combinations. Please show what tables you *actually* have, because it's getting very confusing. And please explain the output, why does `SID: null` appear in some but not others?

Comment: I have added the 2 individual tables that I have and a DBFiddle link (I have removed the other table I was showing as it was a downstream table I had created from a left join). Hope this helps and thanks for your help!